# Open VZ firewall solutions

Tags: firewall, openvz

I've got VPS running on an Open VZ virtualisation instance. Unfortunately I'm having a lot of trouble getting a firewall up and running. I've tried my usual UFW and shorewall, but neither of them would start up.

The company that runs the vps suggested I use csf [here](http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html) but that again wouldn't start up. I then tried modifying IPTables directly, but now that wont start up either. Reading through similar, it looks like its open VZ that's giving me the headache, but is there anyway I can get a firewall up and running on my current set up?

Cheers

Comment: Ufw, and others are using iptables. What is the error message that you get when adding a new rule with `iptables`? If it's something like "no INPUT chain" then your provider did not enable all the iptable capabilities for containers. Also you want to check if your on VENET or VETH.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to enable some additional iptables modules for your VPS. You will need to ask your host to add the following iptables modules (for a typical firewall) support to your VPS,

```
ipt_REJECT ipt_tos ipt_TOS ipt_LOG ip_conntrack ipt_limit ipt_multiport iptable_filter iptable_mangle ipt_TCPMSS ipt_tcpmss ipt_ttl ipt_length ipt_state iptable_nat ip_nat_ftp
```

I am not sure, whether they are going to enable all this :)

Comment: +1 sparx. The conntrack issue is well documented with openvz. Probably won't have much luck getting that working. The OP is probably not going to succeed with this.

Comment: @jdw are you talking abou this documentation?  http://wiki.openvz.org/Using_NAT_for_container_with_private_IPs#IP_conntracks

Comment: That and others, yes. I haven't run across an OpenVZ host that would support this for me

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting provider will not enable the required additional iptables modules here is the solution I have come up with for using ufw on an OpenVZ virtualisation instance (I have only tested this on MediaTemple):

**Install ufw:**

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

**Turn IPv6 off:**

Edit /etc/default/ufw

On line 7 change IPV6=yes to IPV6=no

**Edit /etc/ufw/after.rules**

Comment out line 27

```
# don't log noisy broadcast
# -A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
```

**Edit /etc/ufw/before.rules**

Comment out
Line 48, 51, 54, 57, 58

```
# if LOCAL, RETURN
# -A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN

# if MULTICAST, RETURN
# -A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN

# if BROADCAST, RETURN
# -A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN

# all other non-local packets are dropped
# -A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
# -A ufw-not-local -j DROP
```

**Remember to allow port 22 or whatever you use for SSH, then enable the firewall:**

```
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw enable
```